# Trouble deducing the Read type constraint

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

Consider a type

```
data MyBool a = TRUE | FALSE
```

Notice that `MyBool a` doesn't really depend on `a`, but let's make it so just for fun.

Now imagine I want to define a function `isParsable :: (Read a) => String -> MyBool a` which decides if a given string is parsable as `a` and outputs the result as a `MyBool a`.

Naturally, I want to write:

```
isParsable :: (Read a) => String -> MyBool a
isParsable str
 | (null parses) = FALSE
 | (otherwise) = TRUE
     where parses = (reads str)::[(a, String)]
```

Now this doesn't compile but I don't really understand why. I don't think this function is ambiguous because any call `isParsable` would have to force a choice of `a` and therefore make sure that the constraint `Read a` is satisfied, since it's right there in the type signature. Also, the `where` clause forces `reads ::  String -> [(a, String)]`. But for some reason GHC throws out an error.

What am I misunderstanding here and what is a way to get past this?

Answer (score 5):

In standard Haskell, the `a` in your type signature isn't the same as the one in the body. To make them be the same, you need to enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension and explicitly quantify over it, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data MyBool a = TRUE | FALSE

isParsable :: forall a. (Read a) => String -> MyBool a
isParsable str
 | (null parses) = FALSE
 | (otherwise) = TRUE
     where parses = (reads str)::[(a, String)]
```

---

If you wanted to do it without a language extension, you can use a helper function, similar to why `asTypeOf` is useful:

```
data MyBool a = TRUE | FALSE

isParsableHelper :: [(a, String)] -> MyBool a
isParsableHelper parses
 | (null parses) = FALSE
 | (otherwise) = TRUE

isParsable :: (Read a) => String -> MyBool a
isParsable str = (isParsableHelper parses)
     where parses = (reads str)
```

Comment: Oh ok! I had no idea. Is there a way of doing this without a language extension?

Comment: @user1892304 Don't be afraid to turn on extensions; most of them are benign, and heavily used by the Haskell community. In particular, `ScopedTypeVariables` should be on by default. Arguably, the original Haskell Report made the wrong choice in treating the two `a` as distinct type variables, and the extension "fixes" that defect (even if it requires a `forall`).